# What's wrong with forwarding contract?

Tags: contract-development

Deployed contract from https://github.com/BitGo/eth-multisig-v2/blob/master/contracts/Forwarder.sol , got contract address [0xa07946aac9e905b2d0bfc71d9aaa78694d889815](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa07946aac9e905b2d0bfc71d9aaa78694d889815).

---

But after sending coins to this address, nothing happened.
1st time thought that there was not enough gas for this transaction, but if address received coins so 2nd time my coins will be forwarded to creator address, but nothing happened again. Who knows what is the problem?

---

Debug in ether.camp showed me that contract is good and everything should work as planned

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
/**
 * Contract that will forward any incoming Ether to its creator
 */
contract Forwarder {
  // Address to which any funds sent to this contract will be forwarded
  address public destinationAddress;

  /**
   * Create the contract, and set the destination address to that of the creator
   */
  function Forwarder() {
    destinationAddress = msg.sender;
  }

  /**
   * Default function; Gets called when Ether is deposited, and forwards it to the destination address
   */
  function() payable {
        if (!destinationAddress.send(msg.value))
            throw;
  }

  /**
   * It is possible that funds were sent to this address before the contract was deployed.
   * We can flush those funds to the destination address.
   */
  function flush() {
    if (!destinationAddress.send(this.balance))
          throw;
  }
}
```

Comment: use an event like : event check(address indexed _from);function Forwarder() {
    destinationAddress = msg.sender; 
    check(destinationAddress);
  } // to echck what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that there were not enough gas. Default gas parameters doesn't seem to be good.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the contract [doesn't have any code](https://etherscan.io/address/0xa07946aac9e905b2d0bfc71d9aaa78694d889815#code). This suggests that something went wrong with your deployment.

Comment: Very strange, because there is input data with right byte code https://etherscan.io/tx/0x88f2d75c33118ff4b393f20ce4bbada6b450ffe35b66395164a077f96aa4c4e4